# AJAX response in arrayToDataTable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, google-visualization

I am trying to make a google chart with an AJAX call, the response is this string written as an array created in php

```
['A', "Test 1","Test 2","Test 3","Test 4"],['01-06-2015', 2 , 0 , 0 , 0 ],['03-06-2015', 0 , 5 , 4 , 0 ],['05-06-2015', 2 , 0 , 0 , 0 ],['06-06-2015', 8 , 0 , 0 , 0 ],['02-06-2015', 0 , 5 , 0 , 3 ],['04-06-2015', 0 , 7 , 0 , 0 ]
```

then trying to make the chart with AJAX

```
success: function(response)
{

    console.log(response);
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([response]);

    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);

    var options = {
        title: "Projects by employees",
        vAxis: {title: "Projects", ticks: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]},
        hAxis: {title: "Days"},
        seriesType: "bars"

    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById("chart_div"));
    chart.draw(view, options);
}
```

I get the error in my console saying 'Uncaught Error: First row is not an array.'
Probably because he is just putting the word response in the function.

Comment: You're missing two more square brackets around your JSON array.

Comment: like this arrayToDataTable([[response]])? And the array is not JSON.

Comment: You need to convert it to an array, If it's not JSON but javascript array as string then you can use function constructor `new Function('', 'return [' + response +'];')()`

Comment: Thanks man!! I can't figure out how it actually works but it does!